# How to use SPServices search sql query - getting malformed query

Tags: 2010, javascript, spservices, caml, query

I am using the SPServices javascript library to make a search request to sharepoint 2010 search. I am trying this query:

```
queryText = "<QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query' Revision='1000'>";
queryText += "<Query>";
queryText += "<Context>";
queryText += "<QueryText language='en-US' type='MSSQLFT'>";
queryText += "SELECT Title, Rank, Size, Description, Write, Path FROM portal..scope() WHERE CONTAINS ('test') ORDER BY \"Rank\" DESC";
queryText += "</QueryText>";
queryText += "</Context>";
queryText += "</Query>";
queryText += "</QueryPacket>";


alert(queryText);


$().SPServices({
    operation: "Query",
    queryXml: queryText,
    completefunc: searchComplete
});
```

The result of the query string looks like:

```
<QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query' Revision='1000'><Query><Context><QueryText language='en-US' type='MSSQLFT'>SELECT Title, Rank, Size, Description, Write, Path FROM portal..scope() WHERE CONTAINS ('test') ORDER BY "Rank" DESC</QueryText></Context></Query></QueryPacket>
```

And the returned response is:

```
<ResponsePacket xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response"><Response domain=""><Status>ERROR_BAD_QUERY</Status><DebugErrorMessage>Your query is malformed. Please rephrase your query.</DebugErrorMessage></Response></ResponsePacket>
```

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms547531(v=office.14).aspx) for SharePoint Server search, you specify the scope name in the `WHERE` clause, as follows:

```
FROM Scope() WHERE "scope"='All Sites'
```

So you select string have to be like this

```
queryText += "SELECT Title, Rank, Size, Description, Write, Path FROM Scope() WHERE CONTAINS ('test') ORDER BY \"Rank\" DESC";
```

Answer (score -2):

I got it working with the code [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/120c875a-5240-45cc-a587-c6e376872315) (from the solution post)